# How configure gestures on Ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: gnome, touchpad, wayland

On my notebook, how do i configure the touchpad gestures? I use stock ubuntu. My aim are to show activities (all open windows) when i tap with 3 fingers on the touchpad.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup gnome extensions and install  https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4245/gesture-improvements/

It doesn't have a ton of configurations, but its better than the default.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easier than that in most cases.
The problem is that Ubuntu by default still uses X11 and there is no touchpad gestures with that.

You have to switch to "Ubuntu on Wayland" (or Gnome with Wayland, if you prefer), then it is enabled by default and works really well.

To switch to "Ubuntu on Wayland", just go to the login screen (where you can select the user to login)
-> click on the user you want once, but don't enter a password yet
-> at the bottom right you will see a "cog" icon.
-> click that and select "Ubuntu on Wayland"

Then go ahead and enter the password.

Now it should work out of the box and be remembered for the future.

Be aware though, that there are small drawbacks with wayland still.
(screensharing does not work everywhere, ...)
Apart from that it is working fine

Comment: Wayland is set as default on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

SimonEritsch is correct and actually
here is my answer, a minor addition

on ubuntu22 I got the screen share and hand gesture to work

just log in and choose your user, don't log in look at the bottom right corner menu

I chose ubuntu22.04 with Wayland

Answer (score -4):

Si vas al gestor de software de ubuntu (fuente: ubuntu-focal-universe) y buscas gestos, vas a encontrar el siguiente software:

Reconocedor de gestos Easystroke
Controlar su escriotrio usando gestos de ratón

Easystroke is a gesture-recognition application for X11. It aims to be highly configurable while at the same time providing an intuitive user interface. It was designed with a Tablet PC in mind, but it also works well with a mouse.

Tiene buenas opiniones esa solución.

Comment: Since ubuntu 22.04 update, mouse gesture easystroke doesn't work any more......... so sad
can some one help as it is my big productivity tool :)
thanks in advance